# codeigniter not working on linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've made a website using codeigniter framework it's work perfect on my localhost, however didn't work on Linux server ,
I've made changes to baseurl , database , .htaccess
and I've removed index.php perfectly !
but log file show this error when I try to access my url

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/Domain.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/format.php
>   on line 231

I tried to make simple controller to echo"Hello" when I call function test ,

```
<?php
class test extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "here";
    }

    function test(){    
        echo "Hello inside the function";           
    }
}
```

and the answer is

```
> here 
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

there's no function access :/

but when I make this:

```
<?php
class test extends CI_Controller {
    function test(){    
        echo "Hello inside the function";           
    }
}
```

the answer will be

```
Hello inside the function
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

there's function access :3

anyone can help ??!

btw this is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Did you look at /home/httpd/vhosts/Domain.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/format.php on line 231?  There is a reason for these error messages.

Comment: Yes No thing strange  `array_walk_recursive($str, function(&$item, $key)`
and I've use this library many times ago :/ without any problems

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  Anonymous functions are 5.3+.  Anything before 5.4 is EOL now.

Comment: Shouldn't be related specifically for this case, but at least follow minimum of standards: 1.) library file name should be capitalized `Format.php`, 2.) class name should be capitalized `class Test extends CI_Controller{}`, 3.) methods should have visibility `public function test(){}`. You will save yourself of potentially headache in the future. Btw. what version of CI is used?

Comment: yub :3 my php version is Current PHP version: 5.2.17

Comment: what I can do ?!!! I'm using parallels plesk Panel how to upgrade it ?!!

Comment: You could also stick to CodeIgniter 2.2 which only requires PHP 5.1. Questions about upgrading plesk should go to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: My Ci version is 2.2.0

Comment: `/application/libraries/format.php` is not bundled with Code Igniter 2.2. Using Code Igniter 2.2 does't mean every 3rd party library will work with your outdated version of PHP

Comment: Thanks alot :) , I'll try to upgrade my php ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer regarding your "TEST" and not your initial question.

The short answer is you cannot have a method that has the same name as the controller. It will be looking for a method called index, which you don't have and hence the error.

I've written some test code based upon what you had...

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'Hello from the Constructor<br>';
    }

    public function index() {
        echo 'Hello from the Index Function<br>';
    }

    public function test() {
        echo 'Hello from the Test Function<br>';
    }
}
/* End of file test.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/test.php */
```

**The results. (CI 2.2.0)**

If you use localhost/test you will get

```
Hello from the Constructor
Hello from the Index Function
```

Note: Without the index method I get the same error you are seeing.

If you use localhost/test/index you will get

```
Hello from the Constructor
Hello from the Index Function
```

If you use localhost/test/test you will get

```
Hello from the Constructor
Hello from the Index Function
```

Now you do not have an index method. If you see what happens above you will notice that using **localhost/test/** Or **localhost/test/test**, it is looking for the default index method. And the test method isn't reachable as it has the same name as the controller.

Comment: Thank u for this valuable answer , I spent more than 10 hour just to get any solution to run my site :/ , and that push me to try any simple class help me catching the error , I tried what u say and it's run perfectly .